# generating synthesis scripts in Vivado

Tags: tcl, vivado

I have successfully used the Vivado GUI to synthesize a design and program an FPGA. I have located the .bit stream so I don't have to go through the GUI again if I want to program the FPGA again with the same design.

There is a .tcl file as well, but it is the Report generation script generated by Vivado. What I'm looking for is the .tcl synthesis script. Where will I find it, or do I have to do something else to generate this synthesis script?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about the script to regenerate the bitstream.

It should be inside

project/project_name.srcs/sources_1/bd/block_design_name/hw_handoff/block_design_name_bd.tcl

This is assuming you are using a project-based flow. There is also a non-project based flow.

More information: 
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_1/ug892-vivado-design-flows-overview.pdf